# JAVA produce odata

Tags: java, odata

I am a beginner of odata and I want to know how to produce odata on JAVA.
Actually, I am not goning to use odata SDK. 
I am looking for something like SAP gateway on which I can quickly produce odata service, and for both tables and procedures(JAVA methods).
I have gone through ecosystem on odata.org and found JBoss Data Virtualization maybe the one I need but it seems it's for more professional use and it's not free.
Could anyone give some help?

Answer (score -1):

There is an OpenSource project called Olingo which does that: http://olingo.apache.org/

You should have a look at the Olingo JPA library which can be found in the V2 dowload section.